# Xamarin IOS Php Script that accesses MySQL Db

Tags: php, xamarin.ios

I am developing an IOS app on Visual Studion+Xamarin. I am therefore limited to c#. I have a remote PHP file that I would like to call, then interprete results via JSON. The method in the PHP file expects a username and password. It will return a "CONNECTED SUCESSFULLY" or "ERROR" string. Please kindly assist with a similar example. I have searched the internet for the past two weeks, and most people simply respond, with USE API SERVICES. I would appreciate an example for me to build up from. Thanks and kind regards  T Mamba

Comment: You got that response because your question is a little bit too broad probably. I believe you should research more, try reading this for example: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests.html

Comment: you already have a PHP service written, and simply want to know how to connect from a mobile client?  Or do you want to know how to write the PHP service?

Comment: Yes, I have the script. Yesterday I managed to get a response by using http client connection. I just need to decode the response. I still would appreciate a nsurl , nssession example including the json decode. I

Comment: string url = "http://mysite.co.za/MyPerlScripts/userLogin.php?login_name="+ lgnName+ "&login_pass=" + lgnPasswd TextLoginError.Text = url;
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
                    request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

                    var response = request.GetResponse();

                    System.IO.StreamReader str = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                    UIAlertView _response = new UIAlertView("Impendulo", str.ReadToEnd(), null, "Ok", null);
                    _response.Show();